# jQuery plugin for change color of text

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am new in jQuery and I want to make my first plugin.
It should change color on hover, instead of that it change color on mousedown.

Do I have a mistake in my code?

see

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g690fp7a/)

jQuery

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined){
    $.fn.test = function () {
        return this.each(function(){
            this.hover(function(){
                this.css('color', 'red');
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: jquery plugin!! you haven't called any external sources in your fiddle!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined){
    $.fn.test = function () {
        this.each(function(){
            $(this).hover(function(){
                $(this).css('color', 'red');
            });
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: Yeah, its working. Can you please explain how its possible that its working? or send me some resource where I can read about it.

Comment: It's working because _this_ refers to the DOM object and not to a jQuery object. So you have to surround it with a _$_ to make it: _$(this)_. Then, to make it work correctly you must return this to keep the object chaining. And it was lacking a trailing semicolon in the end of the function.

Comment: The first _this_ does not need to be surrounded because, we are in the jQuery object: so _this_ is a jQuery object. While, in _each_ this refers to a DOM object like in _hover_. See jQuery api for each http://api.jquery.com/each/ and for hover http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Thank you, this is the best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/g690fp7a/2/
check this fiddle

```
$("a").hover(function() { 
    $(this).css("color", "red");
});
$("a").mouseout(function() { 
    $(this).css("color", "blue");
});
```

you could use this.

Comment: Its working, but I want to make this in jQuery plugin. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "black");
        }, function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<a href="#">blabla</a>
<a href="#">blabla</a>
<a href="#">blabla</a>
<a href="#">blabla</a>
</body>
```